# ARM Assembly Even or Odd Number in Register

Tags: assembly, arm

I currently have a "Loop" for printing out numbers from R4 and then moving that number to R1 using Stdout. However I want to only print out even numbers. So if I print everything for example my sequence would output as 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 ...etc but I only want to print out the even numbers (2, 6, 10...etc)

This is what I want but I'm not sure if ARM assembly allows this:

1. Check R4 to see if the number inside register is even.
2. If the number is even, MOV R1, R4 and print it out using the Stdout code.
3. Else if the number inside R4 is odd, continue to do the loop until how many times specified.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evenness of a number can be determined by its zeroth bit. Odd numbers have one, even numbers have zero.

In the ARM assembly, to perform a conditional, you do an arithmetic operation that affects flags. To check the value of a single bit, you either do an AND with 1, or do a TST with 1. The latter is AND with no destination - it performs the bitwise AND but throws away the result.
So, to recap:

```
TST r4, #1 ; TST with 1, like AND with 1, will zero out all bits but the rightmost one
BNE Odd ; zero flag not set - meaning it's odd
MOV R1, R4

; Output... Do you know how?


Odd:
; Continue with the loop...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted. Also, is it possible to add all of the printed even numbers? I know they get moved to R1 but is it possible to store these values somewhere and then later have an ADD command to add all of the stored numbers so I can print out the result?

Comment: Sure. Designate a register as the sum total, initialize to zero before the loop, place an `ADD rx, r4` line somewhere between the `BNE` line and the `Odd` label (so that it's conditional).

Comment: In case one doesn't want to use an extra register or trash the original register, `TST` can be used (e.g. `TST r4,#1`).

Comment: Thanks to both of you for helping me out. I'm able to get the addition of all the even numbers as well. According to some ARM powerpoint, TST (R1, R2) sets cc for R1 and R2 which I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @user3311682 `r1` AND `r2` - as in the Boolean operation, not the linguistic conjunction. `TST` is just `ANDS` with no destination register (sets the flags but throws the result away)

Answer (score -1):

```
 AREA program,CODE,READONLY

      ENTRY
      MOV R5,#01 
      MOV R0,#01
      LDR R1,=array
      MOV R2,#06
LBL   LDR R0,[R1],#4

      ANDS R0,R5
      ADDEQ R3,R3,#01
      ADDNE R7,R7,#01
      SUBS R2,R2,#01
      B CHECK
CHECK CMP R2,#00

      BNE LBL
      B STP  
STP B STP     

array DCD  0x10, 0x02, 0x04, 0x06, 0x08, 0x12,, 0x12;

      END
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: Note that the existing answer from almost seven years ago has a nice explanation. Does this answer provide new information?

Comment: What's the point of `MOV R0,#01`?  R0 gets overwritten by `ldr` unconditionally before that `1` is ever read.  Also, why put a constant in R5 instead of `ands r0, #1`?  Also, `subs r2, #1` already sets flags according to it being non-zero; the `cmp` is redundant.  The `b check` is also a NOP; execution would already reach the next instruction without that branch.  Same for the `B STP` *before* the infinite-loop.  Also, for efficiency you could just count odd numbers in the loop and calculate `even = n - odd`.

Comment: It's generally bad style to hard-code the length of a static array, vs. having the assembler calculate it for you.  Your `MOV R2,#06` is off by one.  Or actually off by two; there's an empty element in your DCD list between the two `0x12` elements.  IDK if `0x12,, 0x12` would actually assemble in ARMasm.  Most assemblers provide a way to define an assemble-time constant equal to the distance between two locations, like `array_len equ $ - array`, or whatever syntax ARMasm uses.